# How I can add a whitespace after comma XPath

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

How I could add a whitespace after comma?

I have the next string:

```
hello,how are you,I hope everything is Good,yes.
```

I want somehting like this:

```
hello, how are you, I hope everything is Good, yes
```

With `translate` it is impossible because it only substitutes strings.

```
<salutation>hello,how are you,I hope everything is Good,yes.</salutation>
```

Output:
hello, how are you, I hope everything is Good, yes

I don't have HTML part because I'm using XPath only to read the XML.

Comment: Add HTML/XML sample for the same

Comment: @JaSON I don't have HTML. I only have the XML and its 1 element with the salutation but I have no whitespace after "," comma

Comment: You need to use programming language built-in tools to handle this issue. In XPath 2.0 `replace(//salutation/text(), ",", ", ")` would do the trick